# Unable to iterate over other person's appointments with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to iterate over someone's outlook appointments with VBA. I believe the following fragment should do what I need, however, the line `for each appm in cal.items` pops up a little message box that says

> Laufzeitfehler '-140492795 (f7a04405)':
>
> Automatisierungsfehler

In english, that would probably be *run time error .... automation error*.

Why do I get this error?

```
option explicit

sub abcdef()

    dim ol       as outlook.application
    dim ns       as outlook.namespace

    dim rcpt     as outlook.recipient
    dim cal      as outlook.folder
    dim appm     as outlook.appointmentItem

    set ol   = new outlook.application
    set ns   = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    set rcpt = ns.createRecipient("Deere John")

    rcpt.resolve
    if not rcpt.resolved then
       msgBox("Could not resolve recipient")
       return
    end if

    set cal = ns.getSharedDefaultFolder(rcpt, olFolderCalendar)
    if cal is nothing then
       msgBox ("No Calender!")
       return
    end if


    for each appm in cal.items
        ' Error occurs in previous line
    next appm

end sub
```

Comment: is it because you have `Dim appm As Outlook.AppointmentItem` and you're using `for each aptm in cal.items`?

Do you have Option Explicit or Force Variable Declaration switched on? If so then you will get an error seeing as appm <> aptm

Comment: Good point, but it's not the real reason. I have changed the variable name and added `option explicit` and the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Found some code here: http://www.slipstick.com/developer/copy-new-appointments-to-another-calendar-using-vba/ which would change how you `dim appm`... Instead of `outlook.appointmentItem` it has it simply as `appointmentItem`. So `Dim appm as appoointmentItem`

Edit:  Their syntax also uses `Set newCalFolder = GetFolderPath("display name in folder list\Calendar\Test")` to define the `cal` variable, while you are using `getSharedDefaultFolder`

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can manually add "Deere John" to your list of calendars, the calendar permission is probably not correct for VBA.

Try this to see if Outlook displays "Cannot display the folder. Microsoft Outlook cannot access the specified folder location."

```
Sub abcdef_CalDisplay()

    Dim ol       As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns       As Outlook.Namespace

    Dim rcpt     As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim cal      As Outlook.folder
    Dim appm     As Outlook.AppointmentItem

    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set rcpt = ns.CreateRecipient("Deere John")

    rcpt.Resolve

    If Not rcpt.Resolved Then
       MsgBox ("Could not resolve recipient")
       Return

    Else                ' <----
         Set cal = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(rcpt, olFolderCalendar)
         cal.Display     ' <---

    End If

End Sub
```